# Using System.out.printf and arrays to display grade table

Tags: java, arrays

I'm struggling with my program and I'm looking for some help. I'm supposed to be able to output a table with my student names, all my exam grades, quiz grades, homework grades, and the final averaged grade. I'm having quite a bit of difficulty figuring out how to use System.out.printf to format my table correctly. Right now I'm having the problem where I do not understand how to loop my arrays so they continually print out up to 200 student's names and grades.

I tried to lay it out by doing 3 separate student's grades, but I'm having the problem where it says all my exam, quiz, and hw arrays cannot be resolved to a variable. This confuses me because I've already changed them from a string into a double. If it helps here is the code I used to try and switch my inputs to doubles.

```
// declare Double[] exams using length numExams
                    Double[] exams = new Double[numExams];
                    // iterates through Array exams and adds values from allInfo
                    for (int k = 0; k < exams.length; k++) {
                        exams[k] = Double.parseDouble(allInfo.get(1 + k)
                                .substring(1));

                        // prints out (delete this when you finish program)
                        //System.out.print(exams[k] + "\t");
                    }

                    //System.out.println(" ");

                    // declare Double[] quizzes using length numQuizzes
                    Double[] quizzes = new Double[numQuizzes];
                    // iterates through Array quizzes and adds values from
                    // allInfo
                    for (int k = 0; k < quizzes.length; k++) {
                        quizzes[k] = Double.parseDouble(allInfo.get(
                                1 + numExams + k).substring(1));

                        // prints out (delete this when you finish program)
                        //System.out.print(quizzes[k] + "\t");
                    }

                    //System.out.println(" ");

                    // declare Double[] HW using length numHW
                    Double[] hw = new Double[numHW];
                    // iterates through Array hw and adds values from allInfo
                    for (int k = 0; k < hw.length; k++) {
                        hw[k] = Double.parseDouble(allInfo.get(
                                1 + numExams + numQuizzes + k).substring(1));
```

Hopefully that helps you understand my train of thought. Here is the code that I laid out and tried to figure out as well.

```
if (choice == 2) {
            System.out.println("Display student grades & statistics");

            //Formatting for the heading of my grade table
            System.out.printf("%-10s","Name");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
            System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
            System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
            System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
            System.out.printf("%-5s","Grade\n");

            System.out.printf("%-10s",studentNames[0]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[0]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[1]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[2]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[0]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[1]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[2]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[0]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[1]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[2]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",gradeAverage[0] + "\n");

            System.out.printf("%-10s",studentNames[1]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[3]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[4]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[5]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[3]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[4]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[5]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[3]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[4]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[5]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",gradeAverage[1] + "\n");

            System.out.printf("%-10s",studentNames[2]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[6]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[7]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[8]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[6]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[7]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[8]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[6]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[7]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[8]);
            System.out.printf("%-5.1f",gradeAverage[2] + "\n");


                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a POJA. Create a POJO of Sudent which contains all your required fields. And then create an arrary of Student object and iterate through it. But for your current code use the following solution.

Maintain the index of all 4 arrays (i.e.  student names, all my exam grades, quiz grades, homework grades).

```
int studentNameIndex = 0;
int examGradeIndex = 0;
int quizGradeIndex = 0;
int homeworkGradeIndex = 0;
int gradeAverageIndex = 0;

System.out.println("Display student grades & statistics");

//Formatting for the heading of my grade table
System.out.printf("%-10s","Name");
System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
System.out.printf("%-5s","Exam");
System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
System.out.printf("%-5s","Quiz");
System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
System.out.printf("%-7s","HWork");
System.out.printf("%-5s","Grade\n");

for(int index = 0; index < studentNames.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s",studentNames[studentNameIndex]);
    System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex]);
    System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex+1]);
    System.out.printf("%-5.1f",exams[examGradeIndex+2]);
    System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[quizGradeIndex]);
    System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[quizGradeIndex+1]);
    System.out.printf("%-5.1f",quizzes[quizGradeIndex+2]);
    System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[homeworkGradeIndex]);
    System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[homeworkGradeIndex+1]);
    System.out.printf("%-7.1f",hw[homeworkGradeIndex+2]);
    System.out.printf("%-5.1f",gradeAverage[gradeAverageIndex] + "\n");

    studentNameIndex++;
    examGradeIndex+=3;
    quizGradeIndex+=3;
    homeworkGradeIndex+=3;
    gradeAverageIndex++;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! This makes it a lot easier than what I did. I do have another question. How would you go about calculating your gradeAverage, and then doing the weighted grade average?

Comment: The arrays mess me up and it makes it difficult to get the exam, quiz, and homework averages, then get the weighted grad average.

Comment: Use POJO to calculate the average without any mess. To answer you correctly, let me know the formula for your weighted grade.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the `"\n"`, in the line

```
System.out.printf("%-5.1f",gradeAverage[2] + "\n");
```

replace with

```
System.out.printf("%-5.1f \n",gradeAverage[1]);
```

or use this

```
System.out.printf("%-5.1f",gradeAverage[2]);
System.out.printf("\n");
```